# Unable to run docker without sudo

Tags: sudo, docker

I have followed the commands for the post-installation to run docker without sudo, but unfortunately, it still will not work.

I have done the following:

- Created the docker group Added the user to the group
- Did the newgrp docker command each time
- Rebooted the system (sudo reboot)
- Logged out/logged in
- Changed the docker.sock ownership to that user and the docker group
- Reviewed the .bashrc file to see if there was any commands related to docker that may affect it
- Checked the config docker file and the host is /var/run/docker.sock
- Deleted the docker group and re-did all the steps

I've read through multiple posts and still unable to get it working.

Command prompt snipit:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPbE8.png

Any ideas what may be the issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I created a new user and added that user to the docker group. That allowed me to run docker without sudo.